# How do I collapse an array of arrays into an array of all the elements?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of the form: [ [ null, 1, 2, null ], [ 9 ], [ 2, null, null ] ]

And I would like a simple function to return me [ 1, 2, 9, 2 ] where, as you can see, eliminates the null.

I need this because some values in the database are returned in this form, and I would then make a query with the example returned but without the nulls.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to completely flatten the array and remove the `null`? Is the array *always* one level deep?

Comment: Yes and yes, always one level deep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> always one level deep

```
var arr  = [ [ null, 1, 2, null ], [ 9 ], [ 2, null, null ] ],
    arr2 = [];

arr2 = (arr2.concat.apply(arr2, arr)).filter(Boolean);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c2kUT/4/)

Comment: Can't get away from a loop, eh? Very well, this looks the cleanest. I'll accept this in 7 mins when I can.

Comment: @Discipol - removed the for loop

Comment: @Discipol, keep in mind this also removes `undefined`, `0` and anything falsy, which you didn't ask for; might want to replace `!!n` with `n !== null`

Comment: I can modify the filter function to my needs :D

Comment: Obviously, just thought the accepted answer should at least do what the questioned asked.

Comment: The filter could be shortened to `.filter(Boolean)`.

Comment: @user2736012 - that's actually pretty cool, didn't know that. Passing Boolean as the callback calls the `Boolean()` function with the array value (`n`) as a parameter, and `Boolean(null)` evaluates as falsy so it's excluded by the filter

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a possible nested array structure:

```
var reduce = function(thing) {

  var reduction = [];

  // will be called for each array like thing
  var loop = function(val) {

    // an array? 
    if (val && typeof val === 'object' && val.length) {
      // recurse that shi•
      reduction = reduction.concat(reduce(val));
      return;
    }

    if (val !== null) {
       reduction.push(val);
    }

  };

  thing.forEach(loop);

  return reduction;
};

reduce([ [ null, 1, 2, null ], [ 9 ], [ 2, null, null ] ]); 
// [1, 2, 9, 2]

reduce([1, 3, 0, [null, [undefined, "what", {a:'foo'}], 3], 9001]);
// [1, 3, 0, undefined, "what", Object, 3, 9001]
```

like this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LoDash](http://lodash.com/) library to achieve this.

[`_.flatten()`](http://lodash.com/docs#flatten)

> Flattens a nested array (the nesting can be to any depth).

[`_.compact()`](http://lodash.com/docs#compact)

> Creates an array with all falsey values removed. The values false,
>   null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN are all falsey.

Here is [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/skmasq/DCKgF/)

```
var test = [
    [null, 1, 2, null],
    [9],
    [2, null, null]
];
test = _.flatten(test);
test = _.compact(test);
console.log(test)
```

Output:
`[1, 2, 9, 2]`